# When I run CLI commands in magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2, cli, vendor

When I run CLI commands in magento 2.2 `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` I'm getting following error.

```
[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]                  
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out  

  [PDOException]                               
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out  

setup:upgrade [--keep-generated] [--magento-init-params="..."]
```

Also I get the same thing when I try to run: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

```
Requested languages: en_US
Requested areas: frontend, adminhtml
Requested themes: Magento/blank, Magento/luma, BA/mypres, Magento/backend



  [Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]                  
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out  

  [PDOException]                               
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out  



setup:static-content:deploy [-d|--dry-run] [--no-javascript] [--no-css] [--no-less] [--no-images] [--no-fonts] [--no-html] [--no-misc] [--no-html-minify] [-t|--theme[="..."]] [--exclude-theme[="..."]] [-l|--language[="..."]] [--exclude-language[="..."]] [-a|--area[="..."]] [--exclude-area[="..."]] [-j|--jobs[="..."]] [--symlink-locale] [languages1] ... [languagesN]
```

Hardly anything works with CLI..

I tried to run the upgrade with -vvv. This was the output.

php bin/magento setup:upgrade -vvv

[InvalidArgumentException]
  There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.

```
Exception trace:
 () at /home/timothy/Public/www/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:501
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->findNamespace() at /home/timothy/Public/www/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:535
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find() at /home/timothy/Public/www/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:192
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/timothy/Public/www/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:96
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /home/timothy/Public/www/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/timothy/Public/www/bin/magento:23
```

Comment: Can you check if the database is up & running and credentials are correct? are you using AWS? make sure its server is up and running if use

Comment: localhost with docker containers

Comment: I logged into the mariadb container and ran the status command and here's the output: Uptime: 75384 Threads: 20 Questions: 330211 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 6339126 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 400 Queries per second avg: 4.380

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your sql server is up and running fine. Magento has specific system requirement. It works fine when you have all the resources required to run a Magento2 setup properly. Please visit below links for required resources:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Please compare with resources you have and take necessary steps to get required setup in case.

Comment: I logged into the mariadb container and ran the status command and here's the output: Uptime: 75384  Threads: 20  Questions: 330211  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 6339126  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 400  Queries per second avg: 4.380